# Text rotates in Internet explorer but the div remains upright.

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a couple of side tabs that work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but mess up when in IE. Would really appreciate someone helping me. Heres a link to them working http://www.sgsgrass.co.uk/quotation.php

```
color: #FFF;
height: 40px;
width: 200px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 40px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
writing-mode: tb-rl;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 0px;
-moz-transform-origin: 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px;
-o-transform-origin: 20px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
transform-origin: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-width: 4px;
border-right-width: 4px;
border-bottom-width: 4px;
border-left-width: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing

-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use images instead pure CSS3, because of issues with IE browsers.

I've tested this site http://www.cssrotate.com/ in IE8 and CSS3 transformations doesn't work. But, in case you don't want images, you can use `filter` to rotate elements in IE. Here are [LINK1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LINK2](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation). You can see nice demos [HERE](http://www.aquim.com/web-article-226.html) (open in IE to see rotation). That is for beginning, you can google it for more.

example of use:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

The rotation property of the BasicImage filter can accept one of four values: 0, 1, 2, or 3 which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degress respectively.